# Web service for converting MS Office file formats (doc, docx, ppt, etc) into plain text?

Tags: web-services, ms-office, xls, doc

Larger context: we're working on an Intranet portal's search engine, which needs to be able to search within *ALL* office types: doc, docx, xls,xlsx, ppt, and pptx. Having the search algo already in place, we've implemented the indexer using Office automation; however, client is concerned, that this is 1, error-prone, and 2, not recommended by Microsoft (and also -not covered in their license).

I've read the previous answers in this regard on SO, however it would require us to integrate an extremely large amount of distinct libraries to cover all the edges, which we don't have the resource to do so.

Hence, we're looking for a simple web service, to which we can submit any of these documents, and would return a simple, plain text (or html, or even PDF -we've got parsers for both) output.

Are there any such services (free, or paid), that covers all of the file formats above?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) - it's free and open source. It allows to extract text contents from MS Office file formats (and from other popular formats, too). There is a server application included which you can run on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure about the service, however if you can managed and deploy three .NET assemblies for DOC/DOCX, XLS/XLSX, and PPT/PPTX. Then you may try [Aspose components](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.total-product-family/default.aspx) -- Aspose.Words, Aspose.Cells, and Aspose.Slides respectively. These DLLs don't require MS Office to be installed on your server and they work fine on any Windows OS and on 32-bit/64-bit environments. You may also see the [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/index.html). These components provide many advanced features to deal with document elements as well. Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Your price range is waaay out of proportion to the benefit it might provide to our project. If you have anything we can use for read-only access, we might reconsider.

Comment: I don't need to update, or create any of these documents -merely to convert them to plain text files- hence, a minimized subset of the features: open document, save as text file would cover my full use case. Do you have anything like that in stock?

Comment: I'm afraid, currently such subset is not available.